# How to get cmake to find size of type in third-party header mpi.h?

Tags: cmake, mpi

I am working on a free-software project which involves high performance computing and the MPI library.

In my code, I need to know the size of the MPI_Offset type, which is defined in mpi.h.

Normally such projects would be build using autotools and this problem would be easily solved. But for my sins, I am working with a CMake build and I can't find any way to perform this simple task. But there must be a way to do - it is commonly done on autotools projects, so I assume it is also possible in CMake.

When I use:

```
check_type_size("MPI_Offset" SIZEOF_MPI_OFFSET)
```

It fails, because mpi.h is not included in the generated C code.

Is there a way to tell check_type_size() to include mpi.h?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done via `CMAKE_EXTRA_INCLUDE_FILES`:

```
INCLUDE (CheckTypeSize) 

find_package(MPI)
include_directories(SYSTEM ${MPI_INCLUDE_PATH})

SET(CMAKE_EXTRA_INCLUDE_FILES "mpi.h")
check_type_size("MPI_Offset" SIZEOF_MPI_OFFSET)
SET(CMAKE_EXTRA_INCLUDE_FILES)
```

It may be more common to write platform checks with autotools, so here is some more information on [how to write platform checks with CMake](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:How_To_Write_Platform_Checks).

<sup>On a personal note, while CMake is certainly not the most pleasant exercise, for me autotools is reserved for the capital sins. It is really hard to me to defend CMake, but in this instance, it is [even documented](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CheckTypeSize.html). Naturally, setting a separate "variable" that you even have to reset after the fact, instead of just passing it as a parameter, is clearly conforming to the surprising "design principles" of CMake.</sup>

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly.

Comment: Regarding your sentiment, there's a workaround for the need to reset the variables: [CMakePushCheckState](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CMakePushCheckState.html). In no way is it elegant, but it's still better than nothing.